# Php para determinar valores duplicados en archivo *.csv

Tags: php, csv

Estoy intentando realizar una función en php para que lea un archivo *.csv y en una columna determinada compruebe si algún dato se repite antes de insertar los datos en la base de datos. Es decir, no quiero que se inserten los datos si hay datos repetidos.

El código utilizado para el formulario es el siguiente:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sin título</title>
</head>
<form action="fff.php" method="post" runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="archivo" id="archivo">

    <input type="submit">
    <input name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" type="hidden" value="20000" />
</form>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

y el archivo fff.php que lee el archivo *.csv es el siguiente:

```
<?php 

    $filename = $_FILES["archivo"]["tmp_name"];
    $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
    $data = fgetcsv($handle, 500, ";");
    $ids = array();


    $res=0;
    $i=0;    
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 500, ";")) !== FALSE) { 
    $i++;

         if (!in_array($data[2],$ids)) {
            $ids[] = $data[2];
             $res="no duplicado";

         }else {$res="duplicado";}
    }
    echo $res;
    fclose($handle);

    ?>
```

El archivo *.csv de prueba contiene estos datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La columna que no quiero que hayan datos duplicados es la columna "Ref". Como veis el nº 5 se repite pero no consigo obtener una respuesta de duplicado

Alguien me puede decir en que estoy fallando. 
Gracias de antemano.
Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que asignas el valor de $res dentro del bucle, y aunque en el caso del 5 se asigna "duplicado" en la siguiente iteracion del bucle se comprueban 9, 10 y 11, que no estan duplicados. Esto hace que vuelva a asignar "no duplicado" y es el ultimo mensaje que tienes.

Prueba a cambiar el n11 por 5 y veras como en la ultima iteracion, te devuelve "duplicado".

Para solucionar esto, te propongo añadir una variable array, llamada $repetidos, que inicializarás antes del bucle como vacio:

```
$repetidos = array();
```

Despues, dentro del if, en la parte del else añades ese elemento al array (porque ha encontrado un duplicado):

```
if (!in_array($data[2],$ids)) {
    $ids[] = $data[2];
}else {
    $repetidos[] = $data[2];
}
```

y ahora, si el array repetidos tiene al menos un elemento, entonces la respuesta es "hay duplicados". Este nuevo if lo pones despues del bucle:

```
if(!empty($repetidos)) {
    echo "hay repetidos";
} else {
    echo "no hay repetidos";
}
```

incluso si te interesa, puedes mostrar los ids de aquellos que estan repetidos (los tienes almacenados en el array)

Comment: muchas gracias funciona a las mil maravillas